# Error - Passing arguments to a python script via command line. The python script takes two text files and perform search and replace

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to run a python command like cmd `C:\Users> simple.py a.txt b.txt`. Both a.txt and b.txt are input textfiles that i want to pass as input arguments to my simple.py file script. I am trying to execute this same command this time by passing arguments through another python script simple-cmd.py using os.system() in it . In my simple.py, i am searching for a string in both the text files and replacing it with other string.  I am unable to sucessfully execute this task as the script simple.py does not seem to take the arguments (a.txt and b.txt) passed by me via cmd. Any help how to do it

```
# my simple-cmd.py file

import os
import sys

os.system('simple.py < {} < {}'.format(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))





# my  simple.py  file......

import sys
import fileinput

 s1 = open("sys.argv[1]").read()
 s1 = s1.replace('("version-2.1")','("version-2.2")')
 f1 = open("a.txt", 'w')
 f1.write(s1)
 f1.close()


 s2 = open("sys.argv[2]").read()
 s2 = s2.replace('#896f04','#87cefa')
 f2 = open("b.txt", 'w')
 f2.write(s2)
 f2.close()




Error i get .....

C:\Users> simple-cmd.py  a.txt b.txt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\simple.py", line 8, in <module>
    s1 = open("sys.argv[1]").read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sys.argv[1]'
```

Comment: Please add the error you get when running your script

Comment: you have expressions to access the arguments in quotes as a file name.

Comment: code like `s1 = open("sys.argv[1]").read()` is not going to succeed

Comment: @ Skaperen   yes  you mean  like  sysargv[1]  in  open("sys.argv[1]").read() , but how should i replace it so that it takes file name ..

Comment: @ Skaperen  i need a way to execute it , i am stuck in this issue for long

Comment: Oh and you may want to re-think the input redirection symbols (`<`) in `os.system('simple.py < {} < {}'.format(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))`. I don't think they'll help.